# Is there any sexual implication in девушка хоть куда?

Tags: значения

Has she only her feet loose? Or is she only good all around?

Comment: Половина ответов трактует фразу как нечто целое, хотя в выражении "N хоть куда" этим "N" может быть что угодно - хоть лошадь, хоть губерния. При этом на лошади не обязательно жениться, а губерния не должна хорошо гладить рубашки. Вообще этот вопрос напоминает шутки Николая Фоменко на "Русском Радио".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The colloquial expression **хоть куда** means great.

Examples:

*На Лизавете Григорьевне Муромской, ― отвечал Иван Петрович; ― невеста хоть куда; не правда ли?* (Пушкин, "Барышня-крестьянка").

*Мой Митрофанушка из-за книги не встаёт по суткам... жаль, жаль, да подумаешь: зато будет и детина хоть куда.* (Фонвизин, "Недоросль")

*Поглядел на карты: масть хоть куда, козыри есть.* (Н. В. Гоголь. Пропавшая грамота)

*губерния Крутогорская хоть куда* (Салтыков-Щедрин)

When spoken about a girl, I'd say it means that she is great for marry her.  This expression is about marriage, not one-time sex.  (Often same about guys.)

There is one more sense in "хоть куда": when spoken about relatively old people, it means he/she is perfecly able to do what young people do (work, sex, anything).

Comment: "Бабка хоть куда" - это просто отличная бабка. Может она с пацанами в футбол играет, свистит в два пальца, а понравившемуся малышу яблоко из своего сада подарит. Причем здесь секс или женитьба?

Answer (score 4):

The question made my day.
No, there is no sexual implication in the phrase itself. But given the right intonation or context it may have one - your question is actually a good example. Anyways, it's out of date, I wouldn't use it. If you want to say "she's great", you are better off with "она великолепна" for a formal variant or "она классная/клевая" for informal one.

Comment: It's not outdated but it may sound outdated because it implyes the girl is good for being employed for various kinds of work, not only good in sex but also can sew, weave, cook, etc. This is a very rare criterion nowadays in choosing a girlfriend or a wife that's why sounds a bit outdated.

Comment: Тут на самом деле стилистическое противоречие. "Хоть куда" - просторечное, а "девушка" - нет. Чтобы быть "хоть куда" не обязательно шить, гладить и т.п.

Comment: @Artemix не вижу никакого стилистического противоречия.

Answer (score 3):

девушка хоть куда == attagirl .

Comment: That's the shortest and excellent analogy!

Answer (score 1):

Although it does not normally contain any sexual implications it may sound suggestive in certain context meaning "up for anything" like in this humorous bit from a TV show (http://vk.com/video-21599370_170301829) where a porn producer asks an interviewer to consider doing porn. You can also judge from these comments http://otvet.mail.ru/question/60418286 the phrase does sound ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

Девушка хоть куда is a normal expression. You can use it anywhere you want. The meaning of 'хоть куда' is interpreted from the surrounding sentences  and the meaning of the passage or paragraph. Basically you can use it to praise a woman in a good or not so good way. Context is the key.

Answer (score 0):

ну как русский человек, для которого русский язык является родным, попробую проанализировать фразу "девушка хоть куда", тут имеется в виду видимо, что эта девушка может делать все, что угодно, то есть ткать ковер, вышивать кружева и готовить отменные борщи, этот комплимент не имеет сексуального подтекста, а имеет исключительно "древние" корни, на Руси ценили девушку, которую можно назвать "мастерицей" то есть "способной делать любые дела", то есть "пригодной для любого жизненного уклада" то есть "девушка хоть куда", вообще сексуальность того или иного человека всегда и сейчас, в некоторой степени, это некий показатель приспособленности человека к окружающему миру, "девушка хоть куда" это человек приспособленный к жизни, следовательно это такой человек, с которым не будет скучно и который внезапно не заболеет депрессией и не умрет от скуки. В некоторой степени это просто показатель здоровья человека. Подводя итог: можно сказать, что "человек хоть куда" это здоровый человек

Answer (score 0):

"Девушка хоть куда" означает, что девушка воспитана и с ней можно выходить в высшее общество.

Its means that a girl brought up and it can go into high society.

Comment: Судя по "Национальному корпусу" выражение просторечное, так что о выходе в "высший свет" человек, его употребляющий даже надеяться не мог.

Answer (score 0):

"Девушка хоть куда" means she can do many types of work. She is good not only in one sphere, but is capable of doing many things good, such as cooking, weaving, sewing, dancing, singing, foreign languages etc.

It is often used to mean she is good to marry her.

Answer (score -4):

I can not agree to previous old-fashioned comment (in this case it's like a difference in using of word "gay" in old and modern English), sorry. I think it can be a spiteful and dirty joke. This means this girl suits for ANY type (хоть куда) of sex. :( 
Please, don't use this idiomatic expression in the context.